# What is the correct way to call URL in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, selenium, web-scraping

I have csv file and passing csv data has parameter to python code. In csv file has URL data. What is the correct way to call URL in python. Getting error `Cannot navigate to invalid URL`

*CSV file*

```
ID,category,link
sports_shoes,sports-shoes,https://www.flipkart.com/mens-footwear/sports-shoes/pr?otracker=categorytree&page=1&sid=osp%2Ccil%2C1cu
```

*Code:*

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import csv

with open('mydata.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        #print(row['ID'] ,row['category'],row['link'])
        url = row['link']
        print(url)
        chrome_path = r"C:\Users\Venkatesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\chromedriver.exe"
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
        RegionIDArray = url
        data_list=[]
        data = []
        mobile_details_data = []
        delay = 30 # seconds
        for reg in RegionIDArray:
            driver.get(reg)
driver.quit()
```

*Error:*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\input_file.py", line 24, in <module>
    driver.get(reg)
  File "C:\Users\Venkatesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.
py", line 250, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Users\Venkatesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.
py", line 238, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Venkatesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandl
er.py", line 193, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"messag
e":"Cannot navigate to invalid URL"}
  (Session info: chrome=57.0.2987.133)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b),platform=Windows NT 6.2.9200 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `url` variable contains the link which you want to access. You code is looping through a string and making a `driver.get()` call on each character. Which basically explains the error.

Since, you are already looping through your data in `for row in reader:`, you don't need the inner loop. Simply use `driver.get(url)`.

Comment: if mydata.csv has two row it's opening two different browsers. i want  to open one browser meaning every time URL will replace with same browser.

Comment: @VenkateshPanabaka - Then instantiate the Chrome Driver `driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)` before the loop.